# ne4j-shell and what to escape and how

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to create cypher-statements for import using neo4j-shell. I'm using version 2, M3. And I'm somewhat in the dark as to what characters I should escape in the properties. Heres an example:

```
MATCH (artist:Artist) WHERE artist.kunstnernavn = 'Ditlev Blunck'
CREATE (artwork:Artwork {titel:'Christian IV's vision på slottet Rothenburg',inventarnummer:'KMS64',datering:'-4622274825',teknik:'Olie på lærred',optagelse:'\\foto-02\globus\globus\GLOBUS 2011\kms64.jpg '})
CREATE (artist)-[:CREATED_ARTWORK]->(artwork);
```

I have tried to escape "\" by %5C but then I get an error on globus%5C .. apparantly s% is a special character in that context. Same goes for titels with " -h" .. apparantly interpreted as an option.

Where can I find docs specifying this?

thanx,
Thorbjørn

Comment: Is this the REST API? In Cypher, this seems to work, http://console.neo4j.org/r/g9gbm9

Comment: does using `\`` instead of `'` help?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the back-tick character (`) to quote your strings.

The [neo4j syntax docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-syntax.html) gloss over this feature, but usage examples can be found across the site.